# Why is my code producing number series with repeating digits?

Tags: java, list, if-statement, collections, set

My code should answer the question below :

```
Write a Java program to create and display a unique three-digit number using 1, 2, 3, 4. Also count how many three-digit numbers are there.
//        Expected Output
//
//        123
//        124
//        ...
//
//        431
//        432
//        Total number of the three-digit-number is 24"
```

Now, I used two checkpoints in the form of `Sets` , and `if statements`. First, I check that the

`Random rng = new Random(); String digit = Integer.toString(rng.nextInt(4) + 1);`

doest not match the value at the `index` of the `rngNumString` in the following lines of code:

```
if (index == 0 )
    rngNumString[index] = digit;
else if (index == 1 && (!rngNumString[index].equals(digit) && (!rngNumString[index - 1].equals(digit))))
    rngNumString[index] = digit;
else if (index == 2 && (!rngNumString[index].equals(digit)) && (!rngNumString[index - 1].equals(digit)) && (!rngNumString[index - 2].equals(digit)))
{rngNumString[index] = digit;
```

Now, the second checkpoints is in the following code:

```
Collections.addAll(randomSet,Arrays.toString(rngNumString)); //if not added individually, then a Hash code is passed and not the value.
randomSetTest = new HashSet<>(randomSet);}
randomList = new ArrayList<>(randomSetTest);
```

As you know, sets do not return values that are duplicate. So this should ensure that my series are not repeating.

Yet, when I print my results, this is what I get:

`This is a randomList: [[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 2], [1, 4, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 4], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 4], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 1], [2, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 4], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 4], [3, 3, 1], [3, 3, 2], [3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 2], [4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 3], [4, 2, 1], [4, 2, 3], [4, 3, 1], [4, 3, 2], [4, 4, 1], [4, 4, 2], [4, 4, 3]]`

`This is the size of randomList: 36`

You can immediately spot the repeating digits in each series.  Now I am not asking, and I do not want the answer to the challenge question. I just need to know why my checkpoints are failing, I need a code analysis please.

As you can see, the if statements, and the use of the Sets, did not prevent repeating digits in my series. I need to produce many series of numbers without repetition. So, please do not resolve the challenge question for me, just the issue in my code. I hope that this is clear. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Here is my full code for your review:

```
void uniqueString() { //here begins uniqueString().


    Set<String> randomSet = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> randomSetTest = new HashSet<>();

    String[] rngNumString = {"0","0","0"};
    ArrayList<String> randomList = new ArrayList<>();

    while (randomList.size() < 36) {

        for (int index = 0; index < rngNumString.length; index++) {
            Random rng = new Random();
            String digit = Integer.toString(rng.nextInt(4) + 1);

                if (index == 0 )
                    rngNumString[index] = digit;
                else if (index == 1 && (!rngNumString[index].equals(digit) && (!rngNumString[index - 1].equals(digit))))
                    rngNumString[index] = digit;
                else if (index == 2 && (!rngNumString[index].equals(digit)) && (!rngNumString[index - 1].equals(digit)) && (!rngNumString[index - 2].equals(digit)))
                {rngNumString[index] = digit;
                    Collections.addAll(randomSet,Arrays.toString(rngNumString)); //if not added individually, then a Hash code is passed and not the value.
                    randomSetTest = new HashSet<>(randomSet);}
                    randomList = new ArrayList<>(randomSetTest);

        }

    }

    Collections.sort(randomList);
    System.out.println("This is a randomList: " + randomList);
    System.out.println("This is the size of randomList: " + randomList.size());

}  //here ends uniqueString()
```

Comment: @user16320675, it’s because I was fixated on creating a unique answer to  test myself. I know that this is the wrong focus to have. But I want to use all new skills learned until I memorize them. Then I’ll go for the most effective answers instead. Nonetheless I am practicing some fine-tuning I’ve learned. This can be seen in my use of variables and declarations only when they are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the last number you got was 1,2,3.

Now the following happens:

- First random digit 2, now we have 2,2,3, because we always set the first one.
- Second random digit 2, the digit will be ignored, we still have 2,2,3.
- Third random digit, 1, different to the existing digits, so it gets set into `rngNumString` and we store 2,2,1 into the set.

Comment: Wow, this explains everything. I forgot to reset rngNumString. Thank you @tgdavies, you are great, man.

Comment: I had not realized it was a different person. This is embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your excessive output is that duplicate numbers appear in a single result, such as 1, 1, 2, where 1 appears twice, it should only appear once.

I respect the code you wrote, so I made modifications based on your foundation

```
 static void uniqueString() { //here begins uniqueString().


    Set<String> randomSet = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> randomSetTest = new HashSet<>();
    // No need for 0, so start from 1 
    String[] rngNumString = {"1", "1", "1"};
    ArrayList<String> randomList = new ArrayList<>();

    while (randomList.size() < 24) {

        for (int index = 0; index < rngNumString.length; index++) {
            Random rng = new Random();
            String digit = Integer.toString(rng.nextInt(4) + 1);
            if (index == 0)
                rngNumString[index] = digit;
            else if (index == 1 && (!rngNumString[index].equals(digit) && (!rngNumString[index - 1].equals(digit))))
                rngNumString[index] = digit;
            else if (index == 2 && (!rngNumString[index].equals(digit)) && (!rngNumString[index - 1].equals(digit)) && (!rngNumString[index - 2].equals(digit))) {
                rngNumString[index] = digit;
            }
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(rngNumString));
            if (set.size()<3) {continue;}
            Collections.addAll(randomSet, Arrays.toString(rngNumString)); //if not added individually, then a Hash code is passed and not the value.
            randomList = new ArrayList<>(randomSet);

        }

    }

    Collections.sort(randomList);
    System.out.println("This is a randomList: " + randomList);
    System.out.println("This is the size of randomList: " + randomList.size());

}
```

After you learn more, such as recursion, you can try to understand this code.

```
public class Solution2 {
static List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
    boolean[] used = new boolean[nums.length];
    dfs(nums,0,used,new ArrayList<>());
    System.out.println(ans);
    System.out.println(ans.size());
}
public static void dfs(int[] nums, int index,boolean[] used,List<Integer> path) {
    if (path.size()==3) {
        ans.add(new ArrayList<>(path));
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (used[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        used[i] = true;
        path.add(nums[i]);
        dfs(nums, index+1, used, path);
        used[i] = false;
        path.remove(path.size()-1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please explain how your code below resets rngNumString or prevents duplicate digits in a series? I can see how it prevents a duplicate series, but not a duplicate digit within a series. Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(rngNumString)); if (set.size()<3) {continue;} Collections.addAll(randomSet, Arrays.toString(rngNumString)); //if not added individually, then a Hash code is passed and not the value.  randomList = new ArrayList<>(randomSet);

Comment: @Iant And I apologize for the mixup.

Comment: `Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(rngNumString)); if (set.size()<3) {continue;}` this code will prevent duplicate digit within a series. `Set` can deduplicate the data,for example, `set.add(1); set.add(1);` add two duplicate numbers to the set, only one will be retained in the end

Comment: `Set` can deduplicate the data,for example, `set.add(1); set.add(1);` add two duplicate numbers to the set, only one will be retained in the end, so there only be one 1 in set. For your code , if `rngNumString` is '1','1','2'  for example, after add these to `set`, number '1' is Repetitive, so only one '1' will be retained,finally '1','2' in `set`, the `set` size will less than three, which means there are duplicate numbers in `rngNumString`. @CodingNoobUnfiltered